# Laravel, using model method as property

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and playing around with it. Sorry if this is a silly question. I just could not figure out how eloquent relationships work. For example:

```
// we have posts and comments related to them
class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

Now we can do this to get comments of the specified post:

```
$comments = $post->comments;
```

The first question is: how can be this possible. Where in Laravel the name of the method declared as a property.

The second question is: how can I use Comment class without calling it on the head of the file with 'use' statement. (use App\Comments)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Answer to Question 1: Laravel uses the magic [`__get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) method to access the method as property which internally calls many functions to get the relationship. You can check the code [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3464)

Answer to Question 2: You can pass the class path as string as a parameter to the relationship like

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Comments');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and perfect answer. First question is ok.

For the second question I actually meant that: 

I can use 'Comment:class' in hasMany method. But I did not call that class with 'use' statement on top of the head. How can it be defined in the 'Post' model.

Comment: If you don't `use App\Comment` and call `Comment::class` you'll end up with error. So you could pass that class path as a string, to which laravel would create an instance of that class and call query methods on it.

Answer (score 0):

For the second Question : if your class is in the same directory then you don't have to explicitly write `USE` statement
The `Comment` class is in the same `APP` directory so it will work without causing error.

In your case your `Post` and `Comment` class must be in `App\` namespace